# How to extract file properties in groovy?

Tags: file, grails, groovy

I have gsp which has table and i need to display created date time and last modified time of each file which in drive.

I am not getting how to retrieve file properties.can any body answer me.

Advance thanks
laxmi.P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The result of file.lastModified() is a long we can use to construct a new Date object. We can apply formatting on the Date object. The formatting rules of SimpleDateFormat can be applied.

```
new File('.').eachFileRecurse { file ->
    println new Date(file.lastModified()).format('EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss a yyyy')
}
```

Comment: Thanks..i want to get file created time..i tried with file.created() but it is'nt working.

Comment: The Java File API doesn't provide access to creation time. A solution can be to create a Process, execute a 'dir <filename> /tc' command and parse the result for the creation time.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like:

```
new File(path-to-your-directory).eachFileRecurse{file->
println file.lastModified()
}
```

Comment: thanks that works..but i want created time of file also how to get that.

Comment: I am getting last modified as,**Wed May 25 14:28:04 GMT+05:30 2011** at end i want it to dispaly AM OR PM instead of  GMT+05:30..how to achieve it

Answer (score 4):

To get access to properties not supported by the Java File API we can parse the output of a 'dir' or 'ls' command:

```
def file = 'sample.txt'
def cmd = ['cmd', '/c', 'dir', file, '/tc'].execute()
cmd.in.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.contains(file)) {
        def created = line.split()[0]
        println "$file is created on $created"
    }
}
```

Comment: i would opt for this one as we can access time change time and modify time with linux command stat.